# How to set content to -webkit-slider-thumb

Tags: css, safari, webkit

I have a Input of type range

`<input id="counter" type="range" min="0"  ></input>`

with following css

```
#counter {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    background-color: silver;
    width: 200px;
    height:10px;
    border-radius:50px;
    border-color:rgb(240, 61, 37);
}

#counter::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width:15px;
    height:15px;
    border-radius:50px;
    content:"1";
    background:rgb(240, 61, 37);
    opacity:0.95;
}
```

Live Demo [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/_Sud/JAjEf/)

`content:"1";` of css is not working at all, how to set some text to red color knob in output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`::-webkit-slider-thumb` cannot accept the `content` property. Try setting a background image, instead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but my image content should be dynamic like it should have 1 2 3 etc till 100, is there any solution to make this possible.

Comment: Maybe you could use PHP to generate a dynamic image. Alternatively, you could create an element using jQuery (positioned absolutely) and move it along with the slider.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, can you point me to some references i am kinda new to PHP.

Answer (score 0):

::-webkit-slider-thumb does not accept the content property.

It sounds as though you are trying to use the slider-thumb as a dynamic tooltip for the value of the thumb's width.

If that is the case, then you could place an element ontop of the thumb with css, which takes the value dynamically through javascript or jQuery.

I am working at the moment, so i might try to make an example later but the logic is this:

1) place an element (say called tooltip) with only a number (later updated with the thumb's position value)  to be ontop of the thumb.

2) find the thumb's position

3) place it as the tooltip's position as well, with javascript.

4) use .innerHTML (or .html for jQuery) to place the thumb's position as the value of the tooltip.